# Swift 4 need help to make triangle using (*)

Tags: swift, for-loop

swift4 to make triangle tree using stars(*) and 
its need to look a pine tree, I tried with the below code but it is not working as expected.
Its need to look like equilateral triangle.

```
var empty = "";
for loop1 in 1...5
{
    empty = "";
    for loop2 in 1...loop1
    {
        empty = empty + "*";
    }
print (empty);
}
```

[Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liMfX.png),
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKx4E.png)

Comment: Please add the error you got

Comment: Update your question with the exact output you want and the output you are getting.

Comment: Just make your text alignment centered and add a space in between the stars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite equilateral but as close as you're likely to get with character graphics.  The main things are that you need an odd number of asterisks on each line for centering to work and you need to calculate an offset.

(And, even so, you need output in a monospaced font for this to look right.)

Edit: Some cleanup for readability (and incorporating the change from the first comment).

```
let treeHeight = 5
let treeWidth = treeHeight * 2 - 1

for lineNumber in 1...treeHeight {

    // How many asterisks to print
    let stars = 2 * lineNumber - 1
    var line = ""

    // Half the non-star space
    let spaces = (treeWidth - stars) / 2
    if spaces > 0 {
        line = String(repeating: " ", count: spaces)
    }

    line += String(repeating: "*", count: stars)
    print (line)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ex:

```
      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
  *********
```

Code:

```
let numberOfRows = 5

for i in 0..<numberOfRows 
{
    var printst = ""

    for a in 0..<(numberOfRows + 1) 
    {
        let x = numberOfRows - i

        if (a > x) {
            printst = printst + "*"
        } else {
            printst = printst + " "
        }
    }
    
    for _ in 0..<(i+1) 
    {
        printst = printst + "*"
    }
    
    print(printst)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code to print star triangle

```
for i in 1...5{
    for _ in 1...i{
        print("*",terminator:"")
    }
    print(" ")
}
```

Comment: Wrong. This doesn't draw the triangle that OP is expecting. Not the same result.